# os dados não vão ao banco apesar de não retornar erro

Tags: php

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cliente ( codigo_cliente, nome, data_nasc, sexo, cidade, email, usuario, senha) VALUES (
                '" .$dados['codigo_cliente']. "',
                '" .$dados['nome']. "',
                '" .$dados['data_nasc']. "',
                '" .$dados['sexo']. "',
                '" .$dados['cidade']. "',
                '" .$dados['email']. "',
                   NOW(),
                   NOW(), 
                '" .$dados['usuario']. "',
                '" .$dados['senha']. "'
                )";
    echo $sql;
    $resultado_usario = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(mysqli_insert_id($link)){
        $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";
        header("Location: loginCliente.php");
    }else{
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Erro ao cadastrar o usuário";
    }
}
?>
```

os dados não vão ao banco apesar de não retornar erro

Comment: Veja se assim aparece algum erro: `$resultado_usario = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: Tente editar a linha que tem header, porque ao usar o header o php não permiti ver o que acontece nesta pagina utilizando o browser.

Comment: $resultado_usario = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        if(mysqli_insert_id($link)){
            $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";
            header("Location: loginCliente.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Erro ao cadastrar o usuário";
        }
    }
    ?> tentei deste jeoito não esta dar erro ,mas não grava

Comment: Tenta do jeito que está no primeiro comentário :)

Comment: /*continua não dando retorno */$resultado_usario = mysqli_query($link, $sql)or die (mysqli_insert_id($link));
        //if(mysqli_insert_id($link))
            $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";
            header("Location: loginCliente.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Erro ao cadastrar o usuário";
        }
    //}

Comment: `codigo_cliente` é auto increment? precisa passar ele no insert mesmo? no `die()` vc tem chamar `mysqli_error($link);`  e não `mysqli_insert_id`

Comment: sim , porque nao pus ele como auto_increment devido o tipo de relação do banco

Comment: Tentou jogar esse insert direto no banco? apareceu o erro?

Comment: $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
        if($linhas){     
            $_SESSION['msgcad'] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso";
            header("Location: loginCliente.php");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['msg'] = "Erro ao cadastrar o usuário";
        }
    } 
Tentei deste jeito mesmo assim os dados não vão

Comment: Copie o `echo $sql; exit` pegue o insert montado e teste direto no phpmyadmin ou workbench.

Comment: INSERT INTO cliente ( codigo_cliente, nome, data_nasc, sexo, cidade, email, usuario, senha) VALUES ( '11111', 'luis andre', '1985-05-12', 'masculino', 'Belas', 'luis@gmail.com', 'luisa', '$2y$10$E.Y8TRFXUxQDZ7AalrOgAeOlvTjzXMxVVk/nybZf1NntRiqUP/5bK' )//insertou normalmente ....no phpmyadmin